# F for intoxication

Tags: synonyms, slang

Is there a word that starts with "F" that is related to intoxication?

I have racked my brain all over the state of mindlessness for this, but have yet to come up with a good answer.

Comment: Are you trying to recall a word you once heard, in which case context might be helpful (such as "It was in the northern UK in the 90's", for instance), or are you trying for a piece of trivia, such as "I know have a word for drunkenness in every letter of the alphabet!"

Comment: [http://onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=f*%3Aintoxication](http://onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=f*%3Aintoxication)

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan, I was working on a title for house party "Friends, Food, Alcohol".. I wanted to go with three Fs

Comment: @BleedingFingers That is fantastic!

Comment: @RajMore "Friends, Food, Free Drinks!"

Answer (score 4):

**Fou**:  [drunk.](http://universalium.academic.ru/117014/fou)

**Fuzzled**:  [To make drunk; to intoxicate; to fuddle.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Fuzzled)

**Fuddle**: To drink to excess. [Colloq.] [1913 Webster]

**Fordrunken**: [Utterly drunk; very drunk.](https://www.wordnik.com/words/fordrunken)

**Fap**: ["drunk," late 16c.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/FAP)

**Full**: [May also refer to being drunk. As in D.H. Lawrence's novel Sons and Lovers](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/2979802)

**Fuzzed**: [Fuzz \Fuzz\ (f[u^]z), v. t. To make drunk. [Obs.] --Wood. [1913 Webster]](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/71699/Fuzz)

Comment: I'd be cautious about using _Fap_; it has a more recent meaning that still involves moving your hand up and down as you would while drinking from a pint glass (or a shot glass depending on your endowment) but repeating the action more quickly.

Comment: @ Frank, why whatever do you mean Rhett Butler? Fiddle-dee-dee!

Comment: Fiddling with your dee-dee may well be another euphemism for it !

Comment: @Frank, Scarlett O'Hara and I may know 7 words for drunk but we don't nothin' 'bout birthin' babies, and manustupration

Comment: Interesting. I'd never seen _full_ in that sense in English. Its cognates are the common, generic words for being drunk in all the Scandinavian languages (where there are different words for being full from eating).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - in German too there is a difference between "voll" and "satt", so I suspect in some other Germanic-root languages too. I don't come across "full" being used in this sense in modern British English (DH Lawrence notwithstanding), but it may be more prevalent in Australian or US English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet,@AdamV, the term 'full', as well as 'flap' are likely of nautical origin rooted in  'three sheet toothe wind':  rope/chain "were fixed to the lower corners of sails, to hold them in place. If three sheets are loose and blowing about in the wind then the sails will flap and the boat will lurch about like a drunken sailor.... the original 'three sheets in the wind'.

Comment: The earliest printed citation that I can find is in Pierce Egan's Real Life in London, 1821:

    'Old Wax and Bristles is about three sheets in the wind.'

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet,@AdamV, Sailors at that time had a sliding scale of drunkenness; three sheets was the falling over stage; tipsy was just 'one sheet in the wind', or 'a sheet in the wind's eye'. An example appears in the novel The Fisher's Daughter, by Catherine Ward, 1824:

    'Wolf replenished his glass at the request of Mr. Blust, who, instead of being one sheet in the wind, was likely to get to three before he took his departure.'" -http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/three-sheets-to-the-wind.html

Comment: I can just about see how that would work for _flap_, but how does ‘three sheets in/to the wind’ relate to _full_ meaning ‘drunk’? I don’t get that. I would rather assume that to be an old, inherited, common-Germanic way of expressing the state of drunkenness—one that has just fallen out of favour in English.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet the tension on the ropes and chains corrects the fullness of the sails... 'one sheet in the wind' is less of an issue

Answer (score 3):

*Fuddled?*​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

Falling Down Drunk and Fupped Uck are two good ones.
Here's more than you can shake a stick at:
http://freaky_freya.tripod.com/Drunktionary/E-H.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> [**Flushed**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flushed): a state of intoxication when one begins to feel warm, pleasant, and craves more to drink. When someone has drunk enough alcohol to feel beyond buzzed, but not tipsy.
>
> [**Fried**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fried): drunk; inebriated.
>
> [**Flying**](http://thesaurus.com/browse/flying): intoxicated by alcohol.
>
> [**Floozed**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Floozed&defid=609184): intoxicated by alcohol or drugs.

Answer (score 0):

OED mentions *fucked* as an option:

> Intoxicated by alcohol or drugs. Cf. fucked-up adj. 3.